# Пунктуация при перечислении

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая после слова "гордиться" в предложении  "Могу с уверенностью сказать, наши цели на этом этапе достигнуты, нам есть чем гордиться и есть куда двигаться дальше."

Answer (score 5):

После слова *гордиться* запятая не нужна, так как у двух предложений, соединённых союзом И, есть общий элемент - *нам*.

Comment: А здесь общим элементом можно считать первое предложение

Comment: Простое предложение не может быть элементом другого.

Answer (score 3):

Могу с уверенностью сказать: наши цели на этом этапе достигнуты, нам есть чем гордиться и есть куда двигаться дальше."

1) Есть чем гордиться, есть чем заняться, есть из чего выбирать.

Во всех случаях указанные обороты занимают место подлежащего (у нас есть предмет для гордости, "чем нам гордиться есть")

2) Двоеточие ставится в БСП со значением изъяснения.

3) союз И соединяет однородные предложения, запятая не ставится.